# Pull from an mssql server on LDAP using node.

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to pull data from an MSSQL that uses LDAP. I'm using node.js. I have no problem pulling data from an ec2 mssql database so I know the code works. Do I need to bind an LDAP authentication and then run the query?